# Is it correct to say he was let to go out or he was let go out

Tags: grammar

Can you guys help me with this question:

Is it correct to say

> he was let to go out

or

> He was let go out

Comment: Is he a dog being let out the door?  a prisoner being released from jail or let out of prison? Is he being allowed to do something?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Amen and amen. Devoid of context, almost any snippet can be deemed "correct to say" in some way or another. (Whether or not it's common, normal, idiomatic, acceptable, meaningful or understandable may be a different matter.) Also, I'm guessing the OP wants the phrase, "He was let out," but can't say for sure without knowing the intended meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct. You can say

> He was let go - *released, for example from prison*.
>   He was allowed to go - *allowed to leave*
>   He was allowed out - *allowed to go outside*

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20was%20let%20go%2Che%20was%20let%20go%20out%2Che%20was%20let%20to%20go%2Che%20was%20allowed%20to%20go%2C%20he%20was%20allowed%20out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20let%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20allowed%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20allowed%20out%3B%2Cc0) confirms that you cannot add **out** to the first sentence, and you can't use **to** after **let**, but you can after **allowed**.

You can find out whether a verb is followed by a [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/) (without to) or by a to-infinitive by consulting a good dictionary, for example Cambridge dictionary: Here are the details for [let](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/let) and [allow](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/allow). Alternatively you can use NGram to serach for actual usages.

Generally, with verbs that are followed by a [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/) in active voice, they require a to-infinitive in passive voice.

> I heard him sing.
>   He was heard **to** sing.
>   I made him suffer.
>   He was made **to** suffer

This doesn't, however, apply to **let**:

> I let him leave
>   He was let **to** leave - **wrong!**

Comment: It's interesting how we can say: "He was allowed to go out," but not, "He was let to go out." Yet, in addition to "He was let go," we can also say, "He was let out."

Comment: @J.R. I wonder why the active is fine *"We let him go out"* but not the passive *"He was let go out"*?

Comment: @Andrew, because in the first one, the phrasal verb is **go out**: this is what he was alowed to do. In the second one, the phrasal verb is **let go**, and this cannot take an additional modifier.

Comment: @J.R. Sentence 2 is not OK because when we put **let** next to **go**, we get the phrasal verb **let go** which cannot take a modifier of any kind, and we can't re-parse it as **let** + the phrasal verb **go out**. In the third and fourth sentences, we just have the phrasal verbs **let go** and **let out**, which is fine.